# file_exists does not work for me

Tags: php

i am using following code, but its not work for me.

```
$img1=$info['available_now']; //http://www.jjbsports.com/pws/client/images/catalogue/products/65014201/zoom/65014201_white.jpg

$filename = $img1;

if (file_exists($filename)) {
      echo "The file $filename exists";
       echo '<img src="'; echo $id1; echo '"width="50" height="50"/>'."<br>";
} else {
      echo "The file $filename does not exist";
       echo '<img src="'; echo $id1; echo '"width="50" height="50"/>'."<br>";
}
```

Please help me Regards,

**Found the code**

```
 $headers = get_headers($filename, 1); 
 echo $filename."=".$headers['Content-Length']."<br>"; // size in bytes
```

Comment: What is the value of `$filename` on runtime?

Comment: any errors? what is your output, give more infos.

Comment: $filename value = http://www.jjbsports.com/pws/client/images/catalogue/products/65014201/zoom/65014201_white.jpg

Comment: You cannot check, whether file exists on external server. In case this is your server, you have to use relative path to the file (so without domain name).

Comment: its shows The file "$filename" does not exist, but actually its does exist.

Comment: @Fou: No need to add "[Solved]" to the question title. Simply add your solution as an answer below and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

The PHP [HTTP wrapper](http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) doesn't support `stat()`, so functions like `file_exists()` will never work when fed an HTTP URL.

If the file is located on your local server, use a file path that is relative to your file system. Otherwise you cannot use `file_exists()`.